# Finding repeating values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

After merging two dataframes I'm left with a dataframe where each column should have a value for every 2 cells. But it looks like this:

| Time | Value A | Value B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | nan |
| 2 | nan | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | nan |
| 4 | nan | 2 |
| 5 | nan | 3 |
| 6 | 5 | nan |

My dataframe should look like:

| Time | Value A | Value B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | nan |
| 2 | nan | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | nan |
| 4 | nan | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | nan |

What would be the best way to look for those repeating values so that every column follows the pattern of 'value' - nan - 'value' - nan etc

I tried finding the problems using even/odd index numbers but the problem is that the order of the values is very important. So that didn't work.

ADDITIONAL:
Before merging, the dataframes looked as following:

| Time | Value A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |

| Time | Value B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |

Comment: Please edit your question to show what the dataframes look like before you merge them.  I think this would be the better way to get an answer.

Comment: I read this twice now and still not sure what the desired logic is. Why is the last row of your desired result `time=5, value_a=5`? That `time, value` pair is in neither of the input dataframes.

Comment: What happens to `Time=5, Value B=3` ? Why is that value excluded from your desired output?